# How to make WebStorm compatible with custom JSHint file

Tags: javascript, webstorm, equality, jshint

I'm new to WebStorm. I have a JSHint file (`.jshintrc`) and any time I build my project I'm blocked with formatting code problem (Indentation).

I tried to change WebStorm indentation rules but it doesn't work. Therefore I wonder if it is possible to define formatting rules from JSHint rule?

Comment: Did you enabled `jshint` in the settings for your project?!

Comment: no/yes, I tried the two but it doesn't change any thing

Comment: there is unfortunately no way to import code style preferences from `.jshintrc`; this feature is only provided for modern linters like ESlint, TSLint and JSCS. So the only solution is setting up indentation preferences manually. see also https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2015/08/maintaining-consistent-code-style/ - you may find this article helpful (though it's a bit out of date)